# Durable queue configuration in Terracotta

Tags: scalability, ehcache, terracotta

Does anyone know how to configure durable queue on Terracotta server properly?

> 

Terracotta stores clustered objects on server in files and writes data to them in append only fashion. I want to control how this internal data gets cleared somehow. I have multiple intensive applications that use common ehcache instance clustered by Terracota. There are threads that are putting data, others are reading and removing. Our hard disks are not made of rubber... AFAIK )) Does Terracotta clear removed cache items from the disk, what's the default behaviour, configuration options etc? Thanx, in advance

Comment: I think I've found the answer I was looking for: 
>> Every Terracotta server instance runs a garbage collection algorithm to determine which clustered objects are no longer referenceable and can safely be removed both from the memory and 
the disk store of the server instance

This means that durable queue gets automatically cleared once its persistent objects are removed by disctirbuted garbage collection process. And as far as I understand no special tweaks on durable queue are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any object clustered by Terracotta is durable.

So once you cluster a queue, it is durable.  Every object referenced by a clustered data structure is also durable, so any message you place on the queue will be durable.

If you mean making it persistent to disk, then this setting is controlled by the persistence mode.  For more details, see the [configuration reference guide](http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/docs/Configuration+Guide+and+Reference).

Objects placed into the clustered memory are garbage collected - the same principle as how objects in the Java heap are garbage collected.  Once all cluster references to an object are cleared, an object can be cleared by the distributed garbage collector.  The process is referred to as [distributed garbage collection](http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/docs/Concept+and+Architecture+Guide#ConceptandArchitectureGuide-DistributedGarbageCollection).

You can monitor the number of objects in the clustered heap, and the details of each distributed garbage collection (dgc) run, as well as invoke a dgc run, using the [developer console](http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/docs/Terracotta+Developer+Console).